# Looking for YA novel where son is travelling between alternate worlds to find his father

Tags: story-identification, novel

Looking for young adult novel from the 1960s or 70s.

It was told from the perspective of the son of a scientist who is experimenting with a machine that let you travel to parallel worlds. The scientist is under some kind of pressure from the government.

One day the scientist disappears.  The son decides to investigate his father's notes and diary and figures out he went to another parallel world and could not get back. So the son decides to follow his father into the parallel worlds and make the same jumps to find him, knowing he can't come back.

The son has various adventures in the parallel worlds.

- Dystopian civilization
- US where World War II did not exist.  As a result technology was not as advanced - someone there plays music on a modern version of a Gramaphone.
- World filled with dinosaurs and no humans. Son has a close call with a Tyranosaurus Rex.
- Futuristic world. He sees a woman toss a wrapper on the ground and immediately a robot picks it up. People were friendly.

Eventually Son gives up and continues forward to find a place to live that is decent.  He finally comes to a pleasant park.  He hears a familiar voice behind him and it's his father sitting on a park bench, where he was waiting for his son to show up.

Comment: The Infinite Worlds Of Maybe? https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/9485726-infinite-worlds-of-maybe

Comment: I got a copy today and that's it! Thanks! Now why can't I flag this as the answer?

Comment: @sueelleker You should probably reply with your answer as an Answer, rather than as a comment on the the question, so that the poster can mark it as the correct answer and you can get credit for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Infinite Worlds Of Maybe? goodreads.com/book/show/9485726-infinite-worlds-of-maybe

Comment: :) You've been around long enough. How does this match?